# PHP use variable of class in other class

Tags: php, mysql, class, variables

I basically know php but i am new to all that classes-stuff. For now - love it. 
Here is my problem:

I'm writing a class to do all that stuff around the account-managements. (e.g. create new account, get account details, check if account exists .... )
Within that class i need to do some MySQL-requests. Therefor i i'm using the medoo-class (http://www.medoo.in).

```
class acc{

// Attributes
public static $account;
public $pw;
protected $error;

public function acc_exist() {
    $database = new medoo();

    $acc_count = $database->count("table_accounts", ["column_account" => acc::$account]);

    if ($acc_count == 0)  {return true;} else {$this->error .= "Account exists already!";};
}};
```

Please note the line:

```
$database = new medoo();
```

and

```
    $acc_count = $database->count("table_accounts", ["column_account" => acc::$account]);
```

here i bring in medoo. And ["column_account" => acc::$account] acctually works. As i read in some other posts, i made $accounts **public static**.

now i call my class like this:

```
$my_acc = new acc();
$my_acc->account = 'Luci';
$my_acc->acc_exist();
```

i need to work like that. Doing some acc($account) is difficult in context of the rest of my code.

But as i expected, i get an error:

> Strict Standards: Accessing static property acc::$account as non static

clear to my that static holds the var's value. so i will need some other way. Anyone got an idea?

best, Lox

Comment: You have a typo in the code $accout should be $account I think

Comment: you are right - but that is not the Problem. just changed the Variables for better understanding. was like acc tbacc acccnt before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to have `$account` as static, that wouldn't make sense with the way you're probably going to be using this code, try having `public $account;` and then use `["column_account" => $this->account]`

So:

```
class acc{

// Attributes
public $account;
public $pw;
protected $error;

public function acc_exist() {
    $database = new medoo();

    $acc_count = $database->count("table_accounts", ["column_account" => $this->account]);

    if ($acc_count == 0)  {return true;} else {$this->error .= "Account exists already!";};
}};
```

Here's more information on how to use `static` properly: [Static Keyword in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: thx for your answer. Sorry but that won't work. The line $database->count("table_accounts", ["column_account" => $this->account]); refers to $database als object of medoo-class. That means, if you go with $this->account, you would call for a var $account in the medoo-class and not in the acc-class. That is the problem

Comment: Did you try the code? You're calling a method `count` of the `$database` object (which is of the `medoo` class), and you're passing parameters to the method, the first is a string, the second is an associative array, with a key value pair, the value being the `account` property of the current object `$this` (which is of the `acc` class). It should work.

Comment: hmm... that sounds very logical. wait a minute. i'll try again. maybe i mixed up something else.

Comment: player of the match! you are right. Guess i just thought way to complicated with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a variable that doesn't exist.

You declared $accout as public and static.

But you attempt calling $account.

Replace:

```
$my_acc->account = 'Luci';
```

With:

```
$my_acc->accout = 'Luci';
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer - please read my last comment on the question. Changed that.

Answer (score 0):

Vex is right.  Take off the `static` keyword and use `["column_account" => $this->account]` instead.

Bests,

B.